# como hacer un delete y un update con ajax

Tags: php, ajax, base-de-datos, crud

no tengo ni idea de como pasar el id del objeto que quiero aplicarle el update o el borrado lógico trabajando de forma asíncrona en php.

En esta parte del código estoy mandando el id dentro del foreach según como encontré en internet
para el delete

```
  <a  class="text-danger delete-confirm" data-bs-toggle="modal" title="Eliminar" data-bs-target="#deleteEmployeeModal" type="button" data-id="<?php echo $dato->idSocios;  ?>">
```

De hecho solo me funcionaba en un inicio solo con el primer registro.

Este es el modal para eliminar




Eliminar usuario



<input type="hidden"id="id_d" name="id" class="form-control">

Estás seguro que quieres eliminar el registro?

Close
Eliminar




Acá está la parte del script para mandar el id por ajax.

$('#delete').click(function (e){
e.preventDefault();

```
                        var eliminar= $(this).attr("data-id");
                        $('#id_d').val(eliminar);
                        var id= $("#id_d").val();
                        $.post('eliminarSocios.php',{id:id},function(resp){

                        });

                    });
```

y por ultimo el código del archivo de eliminarSocios.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "fitness2");
 $id_producto=$_POST['id'];
print_r($id_producto);
```

Pero no me da error porque el objeto está vacío, esto también me ayudaría para el update
Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: aca está el modal

Comment: <div class="modal fade" id="deleteEmployeeModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                                          <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Eliminar usuario</h5>

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
    <input type="hidden"id="id_d" name="id" class="form-control">     <p>Estás seguro que quieres eliminar el registro?</p></div><div class="modal-footer"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Eliminar</button>
                                            </div> </div>  </div> </div>

Comment: No agregues el código en comentarios, para eso están los espacios al realizar tu pregunta, se mas especifico en cuanto a tu problema, edita tu pregunta para que sea bien recibida, adjuntando **HTML, JS y PHP** por separado en bloque de código.